# Microsoft Blazor WebAssembly Authorize Attribute and Cookie Timeout Redirection

Tags: authentication, redirect, blazor, logout

I am developing a Blazor WebAssembly Platform under .NET7. The application has many razor components and therefore many controllers.

I am using a custom Log-In and Log-Out page and also a CustomAuthStateProvider in the Client project to check if cookie and some items into LocalStorage exists (this might change) which used to create the ClaimsIdentity. In the Server project I have the respective controllers for login and logout which are creating the HttpContext.SignInAsync and HttpContext.SignOutAsync. The rest of the controllers are using the Authorize attribute to secure the access.

The CustomAuthStateProvider code:

```
//CREATE AN EMPTY STATE
var state = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal());

try
{
    //CREATE INSTANCE OF COOKIE ACCESSOR
    CookieStorageAccessor cookieStorageAccessor = new CookieStorageAccessor(_jSRuntime);

    //CHECK IF COOKIE IS EXISTS FROM COOKIE ACCESSOR
    string cookie_name = "authentication";
    string cookie_valu = await cookieStorageAccessor.GetValueAsync<string>(cookie_name);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie_valu))
    {
        bool auth = await _iLocalStorage.ContainKeyAsync($"{Parameters.application}_{Parameters.enviroment}_auth");

        if (auth)
        {
            Authentication authentication = new Authentication();
            authentication.user_id = await _iLocalStorage.GetItemAsync<int>($"{Parameters.application}_{Parameters.enviroment}_userid");
            authentication.user_name = await _iLocalStorage.GetItemAsync<string>($"{Parameters.application}_{Parameters.enviroment}_username");

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, authentication.user_id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, authentication.user_name.ToString())
            }, "Authentication");
            state = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        }
        else
        { state = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal()); }
    }
    else
    { state = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal()); }

}
catch
{
    state = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal());
}
finally
{
    NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));
}
return state;
```

The Login / Logout Controllers:

```
[HttpPost, Route("/api/auth/login")]
public IActionResult AuthLogin(Authentication authentication)
{
    try
    {
        int auth_id = _IAuth.AuthLogin(authentication); //CALL SERVICE_AUTH()
        if (auth_id != -1)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, auth_id.ToString()), //TAKE USER ID FROM VALID USER FROM DATABASE AFTER VALIDATION
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, authentication.user_name.ToString()),
            };
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Authentication");

            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                AllowRefresh = true
            };

            HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), properties);
            Parameters.httpContext = HttpContext;
        }

        return Ok(auth_id);
    }
    catch { throw; }
}

[HttpPost, Route("/api/auth/logout")]
public IActionResult AuthLogout(Authentication authentication)
{
    try
    {
        int auth_id = _IAuth.AuthLogout(authentication); //CALL SERVICE_AUTH()
        if (auth_id != -1)
        {
            HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            Parameters.httpContext = HttpContext;
        }

        return Ok(auth_id);
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

I am facing an issue when the user has left the application inactive more than the cookie ExpireTimeSpan which is specified into Program.cs and when the user tries to press a button or page into the old loaded page which makes a use of a controller it fails with "Exception: '<' is an invalid start of a value". While I am checking the /api/view that the component usually used behind, it redirects to Login Page. I belive that the action expects a json class while instead has a LoginPage.

The Program.cs into Server:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login");
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/auth/logout");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/");
    //options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\")); //Not Working on Production
    options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder();
    options.Cookie.Name = $"authentication";
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.None;
    options.CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager();
    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
});
```

Normally, I would like to redirect the Client into the Login page again without being necessary to reload the page.
Any ideas?